# N is a number in base 9.Find N when n is divided by 8(in base 10)?

Tags: divisibility

N is a number in base 9.Find N when n is divided by 8(in base 10)? And N can be very large.say N=32323232.....50 digits

This can be done by converting N to base 10.But time consuming.

What will be the fastest approach given that no proof is required.Like in a rapid fire round.Just Answer.

One solution is:
**In base 9,divisibility check for 8 is sum of the digits(digit sum)**.Digit sum of N=25(i.e from 25*3+25*2).Converting 25 to base 10 gives 23.Thus the question changes to (23*2+23*2) in base 10 i.e 115 in base 10.COnverting it back to base 9 gives 137.Now sum of digit in base 9 is 1+3+7 i.e 12.So answers is (1+2%8)=3

How to arrive at the rule in bold.Is there a general rule exist for such cases?Please provide the proof for the above?

Is there any faster way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In base $b+1$  where integer $b\ge1$

as $b+1\equiv1\pmod b,(b+1)^r\equiv1^r\equiv1$

$$\sum_{r=0}^n(b+1)^ra_r\equiv \sum_{r=0}^na_r\pmod b$$